# How to center objects in the browser in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, leap-motion

I have a file written in three.js to output 3D objects to be controlled by leapmotion. The code doesn't output the objects centered in my screen, they are shifted to top right and only show almost 2 sides not 4 as it should.

**Note** the code won't output anything if it is not connected to leapmotion.

Here is the source file. https://github.com/ellinoran/calderan/blob/master/index.html

I attached two images, one that shows how it shown in the browser and the other shows how it should be.

I am using the latest version of chrome and I run it through wamp server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've successfully already created the scene, camera and the object rendering to the scene, you can achieve position the object to the center of the screen simple by using this small like of code:

```
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
```

If doasn't work reply so I can look into the problem further

Answer (score 0):

Also by the way if your object is moving in anyway or repositioning then use the same code but with object name.position

```
camera.lookAt(objectName.position);
```

Comment: Edit your answer instead